# How to get an array for the database from the textarea ejs file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, textarea

I have a textarea where the user will put 5 or more phonenumbers or emails. I need to save information from this textarea to the database (I use Mongoskin) as an array. So it has to be an array with 5 different items in it. So this is what I NEED to be added to the database.

```
var phones = ["1number","2number","3number","4number","5number"];
```

When the user presses the comma, or semicolon, or start a new line, that means that one of the numbers is done, so it has to treat it as one of the array items. What I have done is that I get the value from the textarea, but it is is just 1 array item sent to the DB.

```
var whatidonotneed = ["1number2number1number2number1number"];
```

What I do not need is an array with only 1 item within, while I need 5 separate array files. So I will be able to operate them.

This is the code I have in my EJS file:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">

  <form action="/emailsid" method="POST">
    <textarea placeholder="Type your Emails Here" name="users" rows="6" cols="60">
    </textarea>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
```

and in my `app.js` file:

```
app.post("/emailsid", function(req,res){
  db.collection('emails').insert({emails: [req.body.users]}, function(err,result) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else{
      console.log(result);
      res.render("emailsid", {result: result});
    } 
  });
});
```

I just don't understand how to make these numbers to be single array items, and how to say the textarea, so that it understands that the comma, or semicolon means that it was one of other array items. Because what I get is just one array item, with all of the information within it.

Comment: If you have a string of wrong numbers, for example `var wrongNumbers = "1number/r/2number/r/3number"`, you can use the `split` function on the string. For example `wrongNumbers.split('/r/')`will result in an array `[1number, 2number, 3number]`.

Comment: thanks for your answer!But i think you didn't got it right,i need to have 5 different separate items in my array,so i will be able to remove one of them,or whatsoever.If you know how to do this,please help.I will be so greatful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establish the names of the fields. Changes on your **EJS** file:

```
<form name="recopiled" action="/emailsid" method="POST">
    <textarea placeholder="Type your Emails Here" name="users" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
    <input type='button' onClick="go(document.recopiled.users.value);" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You must add this to your **app.js** and set what will be the delimiter for the phone numbers of the textarea.

```
function go(content) {

    delimiter=","   // comma but you can set any character here.

    phones=content.split(delimiter);

    //  now the phones of the textbox are in an array with separate values.

    phones.forEach(function(value, index) {   
        //  Here you can handle each item.
        //
        //  Example:
        document.write('item: ' + phones[index] + '<br>');    
    });

    //  you can submit the form from here, or whatever you want.

}
```

Please, take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp